# How to check if number is in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

we have a table where we store "range" information in string format (example below). I would like to figure out a SQL Server query to check if values from table b match any range in table a.
The problem is that ranges in 'table a' are in string format and are based on 2,4,6 digit level.
It is easier to show than to write, so I am showing an example how to interpret it. I would appreciate for any hint.

Examples how to interpret particular substrings:

- "230910" - range from 23091000 to 23091099
- "01-05"  - range from  1000000 to  5999999
- "2302-2310" - range from 23020000 to 23109999
- "511310-527680" - range from 51131000 to 52768099

range (table a) (this format is in the table)
"01-05, 10-12, 2302-2310, 250010"

if values (table b) are within the

| range | result | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04 | x | is within 01-05 range |
| 0610 |  | is not within the range |
| 059991 | x | is within 01-05 range |
| 2302 | x | is within 2302-2310 range |
| 230299 | x | is within 2302-2310 range |
| 250010 | x | matches 250010 |

It is easier to show than to write, so I am showing an example how to interpret it. I would appreciate for any hint.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be better as [markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: Show us your tables

Comment: in addition to previous comments your ranges example off on length. bring data to same format and you can compare using BETWEEN function, also, here the code example: declare @var1 VARCHAR (8) = '2302'
SELECT  
 TRY_CAST(
  TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(@var1 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)) +  REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@var1)) 
 AS INT)

Comment: re "this format is in table"... are you saying that besides the hyphen separated ranges, you also have multiple comma separated ranges, all in one column?

Comment: If `"01-05" - range from 1000000 to 5999999` then I'm not seeing `059991 is within 01-05 range`. Could you explain the process?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest converting your sparse "range" spec into a normalized one, by computed column or something like this, but if you can't, you have to do it inline.

Here's one potential solution:

```sql
SELECT  *
,   rangetest + replicate('0', 8 - len(rangetest)) as padded_rangetest
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'01-05')
    ,   (N'10-12')
    ,   (N'2302-2310')
    ,   (N'250010')
) t (range)
CROSS apply (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'04', N'x', N'is within 01-05 range')
    ,   (N'0610', N'', N'is not within the range')
    ,   (N'059991', N'x', N'is within 01-05 range')
    ,   (N'2302', N'x', N'is within 2302-2310 range')
    ,   (N'230299', N'x', N'is within 2302-2310 range')
    ,   (N'250010', N'x', N'matches 250010')
    ) t (rangetest,result,comment)
    ) y
CROSS apply (
        SELECT  LEFT(range, ISNULL(NULLIF(
                charindex('-',range)-1,-1), LEN(range))) AS lfixed
        ,   RIGHT(range, ISNULL(NULLIF(
                charindex('-',REVERSE(range))-1,-1), LEN(range))) AS rfixed
    ) splitted
CROSS apply (
        SELECT  lfixed + replicate('0', 8 - len(lfixed)) AS leftrange
        ,   rfixed + replicate('9', 8 - len(rfixed)) AS rightrange
    ) normalized
WHERE   rangetest + replicate('0', 8 - len(rangetest)) BETWEEN normalized.leftrange AND normalized.rightrange
```

The basic idea is to convert 01 etc into a fully padded string 01000000, and then do the same with the incoming values, after which it becomes easy.

The LEFT/RIGHT thing splits the range into left and right value, and the REPLICATE thing pads it to correct length.

Finally the `WHERE   rangetest + replicate('0', 8 - len(rangetest)) BETWEEN normalized.leftrange AND normalized.rightrange` test checks if the padded test value is between the normalized range.

Output:

| range | rangetest | result | comment | lfixed | rfixed | leftrange | rightrange | padded_rangetest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-05 | 04 | x | is within 01-05 range | 01 | 05 | 01000000 | 05999999 | 04000000 |
| 01-05 | 059991 | x | is within 01-05 range | 01 | 05 | 01000000 | 05999999 | 05999100 |
| 2302-2310 | 2302 | x | is within 2302-2310 range | 2302 | 2310 | 23020000 | 23109999 | 23020000 |
| 2302-2310 | 230299 | x | is within 2302-2310 range | 2302 | 2310 | 23020000 | 23109999 | 23029900 |
| 250010 | 250010 | x | matches 250010 | 250010 | 250010 | 25001000 | 25001099 | 25001000 |

Comment: kudos.  OP's structure is one of the ugliest I've seen in years.  +1

Comment: The `splitted` part could be done with min, max and string_split

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yeah, i wanted to write something snarky, sometimes that's harder not to that just answer :D Salman, true, i was thinking about the lack of positional parameter but MIN/MAX would work here. Oh well, i was busy making NULLIF work and didn't think of alternatives

Answer (score 1):

This does assume that all the strings are well formed. Otherwise if you just split on the dash character you can then easily compare as strings without worrying about padding everything out to eight characters.

```
with splitA as (
    select
        case when dashPos > 0 then left("range", dashPos - 1) else "range" end as startRange,
        case when dashPos > 0 then substring("range", dashPos + 1, 8) else "range" end + '999999' as endRange
    from a cross apply
       (values (charindex('-', "range"))) as d(dashPos)
)
select * from b
where exists (
    select 1 from splitA a
    where b.rangeTest between a.startRange and EndRange
);
```

Making another assumption that the dash is always the middle character, you could even condense it more:

```
select * from b where exists (
    select 1 from a where b.rangeTest between
            left(a."range", len(a."range") / 2)
        and substring(a."range", len(a."range") / 2 + 2, 8) + '999999)
);
```

I doubt that second approach is a good idea though and wouldn't work if there's no hyphen anyway.

Comment: that's clever, no padding needed indeed!

Answer (score 0):

See example.
Test data

```
create table tableA (id int,code_range varchar(30), tax_rate float,comment varchar(100));
insert into tableA values
  (1,'230910',0.1,' - range from 23091000 to 23091099')
,(2,'01-05',0.12,' - range from 1000000 to 5999999')
,(3,'2302-2310',0.05,' - range from 23020000 to 23109999')
,(4,'511310-527680',0.04,' - range from 51131000 to 52768099')
,(5,'250010',0.00,' match 250010')
;
create table tableB (id int,code varchar(6),total float,wResult varchar(1),comment varchar(30));
insert into tableB values
 (11,'04',1000.0,'x','is within 01-05 range')
,(12,'0610',2000,'','is not within the range')
,(13,'059991',3000,'x','is within 01-05 range')
,(14,'2302',4000,'x','is within 2302-2310 range')
,(15,'230299',5000,'x','is within 2302-2310 range')
,(16,'250010',6000,'x','matches 250010')
;
```

Query

```
with tr as(
  select *
    ,case when charindex('-',code_range)>0 then 
       substring(code_range,1,charindex('-',code_range)-1)
     else code_range
     end brange
    ,case when charindex('-',code_range)>0 then 
       substring(code_range,charindex('-',code_range)+1,100)
     else code_range
     end erange
  from tableA
)
-- select * from tr;

select b.id,code,a.code_range
 ,case when a.code_range is null then ''
       when a.brange=a.erange and cast(b.code as int)=cast(left(a.brange+'000000',len(b.code)) as int) 
           then 'e'
  else 'x'
  end result
    ,wResult,b.comment,total,tax_rate
 ,b.total*a.tax_rate as tax_value
from tableB b
left join tr a
  on cast(b.code as int) between cast(left(a.brange+'000000',len(b.code)) as int)
                       and cast(left(a.erange+'999999',len(b.code)) as int)
   and cast(left(b.code+'000000',6) as int) between cast(left(a.brange+'000000',6) as int)
                       and cast(left(a.erange+'999999',6) as int)
```

Output

| id | code | code_range | result | wResult | comment | total | tax_rate | tax_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 04 | 01-05 | x | x | is within 01-05 range | 1000 | 0.12 | 120 |
| 12 | 0610 | null |  |  | is not within the range | 2000 | null | null |
| 13 | 059991 | 01-05 | x | x | is within 01-05 range | 3000 | 0.12 | 360 |
| 14 | 2302 | 2302-2310 | x | x | is within 2302-2310 range | 4000 | 0.05 | 200 |
| 15 | 230299 | 2302-2310 | x | x | is within 2302-2310 range | 5000 | 0.05 | 250 |
| 16 | 250010 | 250010 | e | x | matches 250010 | 6000 | 0 | 0 |

One row may match 0,1, 2 or more ranges.

The example is completely invented